# Query queues belonging to a particular sobject

Tags: query, queue

Is there a way to query only queues tied to a particular sobject?

I have the following query which gets me all the queues.

```
Select id, name from group where Type = 'Queue'
```

I want all queues which are tied only to sobject : CustomObject__C. How can I modify the above query or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a QueueSobject from which you will get the queues along with the object assigned to it.

Please check the below query:

```
SELECT QueueId, Queue.Name, SobjectType FROM QueueSobject WHERE SobjectType = 'CustomObject__C'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [QueueSobject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_queuesobject.htm) for this. `QueueSobject` represents the mapping between a queue Group and the sObject types associated with the queue, including custom objects.

Sample query:

```
 QueueSobject que = [Select Id, SobjectType, QueueId, Queue.Name from 
 QueueSobject where SobjectType = 'Case'];
```